# AngularJS on HTTP calling service on HTTPS on IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, cors

I have my AngularJS application hosted on HTTP that needs to call an HTTPS service. I am having problem to get this work on IE9.

To enable CORS in IE9, I Enable the "Access data sources across domains" in Security Settings in Internet Options of IE9. Even though this setting helps on calling HTTP service across domain, it still gives me error "Access Denied" when calling to HTTPS service.

Is there a way for me to call an HTTPS service from HTTP hosted Angular application in IE9?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this library

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Comment: Yes, I saw a few similar library. If you see in the README of this one, it explicitly says: Only HTTP or HTTPS, Protocol must be the same scheme as the calling page. This is my question.